# Apex to update custom field on Opportunity has unexpected token

Tags: apex, opportunity

Please indicate a relevant post if this is a duplicated question.
I am new to Salesforce and using Apex. I am trying a simple task of updating a
custom field on an Opportunity.

Here is my code:

```
//Select record I want
Opportunity oppty = [SELECT 
                        npe01__Membership_End_Date__c,
                        npe01__Membership_Start_Date__c

                     FROM Opportunity 

                     WHERE Id = '0060t00000EA5VUAA1'];

//Set new date fields

oppty.npe01__Membership_Start_Date__c=2019-03-01 00:00:00;

oppty.npe01__Membership_End_Date__c =2020-03-31 00:00:00;

//Update Date Fields

update oppty;

System.debug(oppty);
```

When I execute my code I get an unexpected token error starting at line:
oppty.npe01__Membership_Start_Date__c=2019-03-01 00:00:00;

When I do System.debug() to my variable, I can see these result:
[image]

When I append my new Dates with a '00:00:00' I get an error that I am using an invalid time.

All the documentation I have looked at indicates that updating a field should
look like

variable.field_name = value;

update variable;

Am I misunderstanding this?

Thanks much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In apex, you use an object (e.g. a Date variable). For example:

```
oppty.npe01__Membership_Start_Date__c=Date.newInstance(2019,3,1);
```

You'll need to know if the data type is a Date, DateTime, String, Decimal, sobject, etc in order to use the correct data type.

Comment: Thank you, my code works now and this helped me better understand the language.